# Copy a pygame.Surface object

Tags: pygame

I'm programming a game in pygame in which you place soldiers and they fight. After they are done fighting, I want the screen to return to where it was before the battle started. I want to copy a the pygame.sprite.Group object containing the soldiers using copy.deepcopy() like so:

```
oldRUnits = copy.deepcopy(RedUnits)
oldBUnits = copy.deepcopy(BlueUnits)
```

However, I found out that pygame.sprite.Groups don't like to be deepcopied. It just raises pygame.error. I tried deepcopying each pygame.sprite.Sprite object in the group individually like so:

```
oldRUnits = []
oldBUnits = []
for i in RedUnits:
    oldRUnits.append(copy.deepcopy(i))
for i in BlueUnits:
    oldBUnits.append(copy.deepcopy(i))
```

However, they don't like to be deepcopied either so I'm stuck. I want to know if there is a way to copy this and if there is a better way to achieve my goal. Thanks!

Comment: Asking your question like this will only allow people who practically know pygame by heart to answer it. If you include an MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), way more people will be able to help you and you are much more likely to get an answer.

Comment: `surface.copy()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a solution to my problem. Instead of

```
oldRUnits = []
oldBUnits = []
for i in RedUnits:
    oldRUnits.append(copy.deepcopy(i))
for i in BlueUnits:
    oldBUnits.append(copy.deepcopy(i))
```

I could write

```
oldRUnits = []
oldBUnits = []
for i in RedUnits:
    oldRUnits.append(type(i)(*i.get_init_args()))
for i in BlueUnits:
    oldBUnits.append(type(i)(*i.get_init_args()))
```

Answer (score 0):

For copying a Surface, I usually just define a new empty Surface with the same dimensions, and blit the old Surface on the new surface

```
old_surf = pygame.image.load("path/to/old/image.png")
new_surf_size = old_surf.get_size()
new_surf = pygame.surface.Surface(new_surf_size)
new_surf.blit(old_surf,(0,0))
```